# How to design uml for php procedural language

Tags: php, uml, procedural

I did a project on web application using procedural php(didn't used oop concepts).
for the documentation purpose i am supposed to design UML models for my application.
as we all know that,UML is object oriented, how can i achieve uml for procedural php??
is there any possibility for doing this? other than changing my code to object oriented!
if possible please mention which diagrams i must design.
I searched in web, but i didn't found proper information.
i was totally confused, please help me out with this.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: +1 A very interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can't use the class diagram(directly). It, and only it is about OOP.

But all other diagrams are opened for use. For example:

- Data diagrams for your DB planning
- Communication, sequence, state machine and activity diagrams for cooperation of your servers and pages.
- Deployment for to plan where will lies what.
- Timing diagram - to resolve the timeouts.
- What is funny, you even can use the class diagrams - for planning UI for a page - every element on the page has its elements and its functions and I use the class diagram for it.

Comment: thanks for ur answer @gangnus .
last point is quiet intresting.. :)